# Data from PHPMYADMIN implement in PHP Page into HTML Form to Send via PHP POST

Tags: php, html, sql

I have data in my PHPMYADMIN in a few columns and rows.

Via PHP I read the Data out of my SQL Table and print it into a table.

The last  of my table is a action button. So the whole table is a echo and within the table there's a html form in the last , but only with a submit button (input type="hidden") but the value should be the "id" out of my SQL table.

Here's the problem. How can I get the id of one row into the value of an input field? . $row["id"]. doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?

This is for a Website where the user can vote a table row up and then with the html form it is sending via http post to another page where it overrides the current number in the database with +1

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM votingpoll ORDER BY votecount DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "$id";

echo "<table>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td> 
                    <form action='vote.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='text' name='id' value='$id'> 
                        <input type='submit' value='VOTE'> 
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: You should really know that `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP for manipulating a **MYSQL** DBMS !

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$row[id]` i.e. leave the quotes off when the array reference is used inside a double quoted string.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM votingpoll ORDER BY votecount DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// remove this it does not appear to do anything useful here
//echo "$id";

echo "<table>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td> 
                    <form action='vote.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='text' name='id' value='$row[id]'> 
                        <input type='submit' value='VOTE'> 
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Or if you prefer you could use

```
<input type='text' name='id' value='{$row['id']}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't setting `$id` anywhere. Try setting it from the results like `$id = $row["id"];`

Full example:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    echo "<tr>
            <td> 
                <form action='vote.php' method='post'>
                    <input type='text' name='id' value='$id'> 
                    <input type='submit' value='VOTE'> 
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>";
}
```